# Jest - Cannot find module '@lib/components' from 'src/components/MyComponent.test.tsx'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using a third-party component library called `@lib/components`, and i tried to write a test `MyComponent.test.tsx` like so:

```
import * as ComponentsLib from '@lib/components';

const setup = () => {
  const view = render(<MyComponent />);

  return { view };
};

jest
  .spyOn(ComponentsLib, 'Comp1')
  .mockImplementation(() => (
    <div data-testid='test'>{'test'}</div>
  ));

it('renders', () => {
  setup();
  expect(screen.queryByTestId('test')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

However, i'm getting the following error:
`Cannot find module '@lib/components' from 'src/components/MyComponent.test.tsx'`

How could then i mock the implementation of `Comp1` from that component library?

Comment: If you indeed have this library installed in your node_modules, then it seems like your error is just because you need to run `npm install`

Comment: I had run it before and ran it again just in case - it unfortunately didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using import aliases that jest doesn't know about (what path does `@lib` refer to? I'm assuming there's **NOT** an npm module called `@lib/components` in your project, but I might be mistaken.)

The solution to this is in your jest.config.js file under the [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring)

```
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@lib$": "<rootDir>/src$1",
  }
```

Comment: There is a library called `@lib/components` in my project (not that exact name, but with the `@` in the beginning)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the right way, but using  `"^@lib/components/$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/$1"` doesn't get rid of the error.

Comment: @Gambit2007 that was my question - can you post your package.json? Is that library referenced in your package.json?

Comment: Yes, it is referenced.